# How to best way to parse args yet make it clear and easy to understand

Tags: scala

I'm putting some test cases and having lots of parameters yet it is cumbersome and not so easy to understand putting them into a liner in scala. I rather specify in a visually acceptable manner but correctly parse them in scala...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use String Interpolation to define the arguments such as below

```
val kafkaServers = "server1:9092,server2:9092"
val pleasentArgs = s"""
   --master='spark://someserver'
   --metricWindowSize=50
   --outputDirectory='/tmp/someGoodDirectory'
   --zkQuorum=$zkQuorum
   --saveToHDF=false
   --userName='jack@somewhereElse.com' 
   --kafkaServers=$kafkaServers
"""
```

And have a method to clean up all the newline, tab etc characters and then generate the args as shown below:

```
def cleanUp(str:String) = str.split('\n').map(_.trim.filter(_ >= ' ')).mkString(" ")
def genArgs(args:String): Array[String] =cleanUp(args).split(" ").filter(!_.trim.isEmpty)
```

So eventually we can just call genArgs method

```
val args = genArgs(pleasentArgs)
```